# Python- Trying to find image with largest green circle

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-3.x, scipy

I have been given a file with hundreds of images. Each image contains a single green circle on a white background.
I need to  determine which image contains the circle with the largest diameter with a python program. 
Each of these images has the same dimensions, so the answer could also be determined by finding the image with the most amount of green pixels, I believe. I am aware that scipy can handle images, but when I try to run the following code:

```
from scipy import misc

image=open("/Users/Myname/Desktop/greencircles/image_0.png", "r")
misc.imread(image)
```

...It gives the error "module" has no attribute "imread"
A I going about this in the right direction? I have searched for solutions for a while now to no avail.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: i would recommend using PIL's histograms

Comment: I have python 3, I was made aware that there is no PIL for 3.x

Comment: This is so weird. ["module" has no attribute "imread"] means that scipy.misc doesn't have the "imread" method att all ! Did you install Scipy correctly?

Comment: Turns out I needed to install PIL... I have no idea why, but it doesn't crash anymore. So I have misc.imread(image), but now I don't know how to find which has the most creen.

Comment: You are more likely after `scipy.ndimage.imread`. To help debug your problem, add the statement `print misc` after the import line and include the full output.

Comment: Ok, my comment came too late, you already solved that :)

Comment: @Vahid I think imread/imwrite were moved in a recent version, from scipy.ndimage to scipy.misc

Comment: @MrE Yes, it seems so ..

Answer (score 1):

Since all you have is a green region over a white region, all you need to do is sum the non white pixels (the dual also works just fine). There isn't much point in using scipy here too, PIL is enough, and the color is unimportant in your task too. Assuming a typical color range of [0, 255]:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

x = ImageOps.grayscale(Image.open('input.png'))
print sum(1 for xi in x.getdata() if xi != 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

‛imread‛ the file path directly

Comment: import scipy
from scipy import misc

misc.imread("/Users/myname/Desktop/greencircles/image_0.png")

Still get the Attribute Error